# How to use DeepL API curl command with Indy TidHTTP?

Tags: delphi, curl, https, indy

Example request to https://www.deepl.com:

```sh
curl https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate \
 -d auth_key=[yourAuthKey] \
 -d "text=Hello world!" \
 -d "target_lang=DE"
```

Example response:

```json
{"translations": [{
                   "detected_source_language":"EN",
                   "text":"Hallo Welt!"
                 }]
}
```

I want to implement the above example in Delphi 11 using Indy's `TIdHTTP` component, but I have not been able to translate the existing answers into a workable solution for me.

Comment: For decades I was sure _"Hello, World!"_ should never contain a comma, but today I learnt [otherwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TIdHTTP` equivalent of that curl example is to pass a `TStrings` object containing `name=value` pairs to the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method, eg:

```pascal
PostData := TStringList.Create;
try
  PostData.Add('auth_key=[yourAuthKey]');
  PostData.Add('text=Hello, world!');
  PostData.Add('target_lang=DE');
  Response := IdHTTP.Post('https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate', PostData);
finally
  PostData.Free;
end;
```